# AngularJS $http: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true

Tags: http, angularjs, cookies, restful-authentication

I have created a session management for my site. Site will authenticate using a service and the details will be maintained in a cookie. I am trying to access the services from my RESTful server but getting errors. I found its because the non-authentication of the request. I hope I should send my `withCredentials:true` along with the request. But when I use this `withCredentials:true` I am getting this error in the console.

```
 Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue. Do you have any CORS management between your site and your restful server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a CROS issue. If you are using CROS in your site, just don't use wild cards in access-control-allow-origin. You need to mention your inputs there. Only one site can be given permissions at a time. You can't give permissions to access with two or more domain names. If you want to do that, you need to add another way to server for that domain. May be with different requesting url or so.